# How to verify the type/name of token received in a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, tokens

Here is a sample contract which is designed to take `xyz token`. How can the contract verify that the sent is the `xyz token`?

```
pragma "^0.7.0"

contract myContract {
  address public payable owner;
  uint public value;  //<<==xyz token

  constructor(uint _value) payable {
    owner = msg.sender;
    value = _value;  //<<== how does the contract verify it is the _value of xyz token?
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to achieve, but any token transfers will need to send a transaction to the token contract. You might want to read a bit about how to interact with tokens.

Comment: Do you have a good post to recommend? I look online and there are few talking about the interaction between token contract and the contracts which use the token. My understanding is that the token contract shall have a deploying address and the contract which uses the token shall have a way to refer the token contract.

Answer (score 3):

To receive ERC20 payments you usually use the combination of user's approval and transferFrom from the contract.

1. User calls token's `approve` function with the recipient contract address. Using a wallet, perhaps Metamask. In javascript it will look like:

   ```
    token.approve(recipientContactAddress, amount, { from: userAddress });
   ```
2. User calls a function from the recipient contract, deposit, let's call that function `deposit`.

   ```
    recipientContract.deposit(amount, { from: userAddress });
   ```
3. Recipient contract calls token's `transferFrom`

   ```
    function deposit(uint256 amount) public {
        require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount), "transferFrom failed");
    }
   ```

Comment: How can a contract which uses the token creates an instance of the token for reference? The token may likely have already been deployed (with deploying address). Maybe the question of how a child contract can inherit from the token contract? I am looking for a way to refer the token in child contract which uses the token.

Comment: @user938363 If you know the address you can hardcode in the contract, or pass as parameter to the constructor. For example using OpenZeppelins `IERC20 token = IERC20(0x12341234..);`

Answer (score 0):

In this [post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50507/solidity-smart-contract-inherited-function-output-failed), the answer for case 1 `There is a contract A and a contract B and they need to communicate. A is not B and B is not A, but A needs enough information about B in order to communicate with it, and the reverse.` answers my question.